# Exploding Pandas Columns strings by characters (dot product)

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark

Lets say I have this dataframe

```
+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------------------------+
|col1    |col2   |...  |col99  | Other irrelevant columns |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------------------------+
|A       |AB     |...  |TG     |irrelevant value 1        |
|G       |TC     |...  |AGC    |irrelevant value 2        |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------------------------+
```

I would like to explode each row as to have only one character in each row(all possible one-character combinations), in case of the first row we would have 4 rows (2x2) and in the case of the second row would be 6 rows (2x3)

I am able to achieve this with the following code but since I have 99 columns to do this my implementation is painfully slow and doesn't finish, I have to interrupt; and I am sure there is a faster way to do this.

```
df_copy=df.copy()
test=pd.DataFrame()
column_sequences=[col1,col2,...,col99]
for i in column_sequences:

    for index, row in df_copy.iterrows():
        if len(row[i])==1:
            test=test.append(row)
            count=+1
        elif len(row[i])>1:


            changes=list(row[i])
            for j in changes:
                row_copy=row.copy()
                row_copy[i]=j
                test=test.append(row_copy)

            count2=+1
    df_copy=test.copy()
    test=pd.DataFrame()
```

Desired output:

```
+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------------------------+
|col1    |col2   |...  |col99  | Other irrelevant columns |
+--------+-------+-----+-------+--------------------------+
|A       |A      |...  |T      |irrelevant value 1        |
|A       |A      |...  |G      |irrelevant value 1        |
|A       |B      |...  |T      |irrelevant value 1        |
|A       |B      |...  |G      |irrelevant value 1        |

etc...
```

Comment: Your strings dont have any seperator?

Comment: No, no separator between the strings :(